# javafx with swt : SWT.error() using animation

Tags: java, oracle, javafx, swt

I'm developing an RCP application which uses some JavaFX controls and animations.
Using the "Oracle Java Mission Control tool". I saw that I have a hot JavaFX Thread that is running (a lot) into a SWT.error.

I reproduced this behavior using the oracle snippet (http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/swt_interoperability/jfxpub-swt_interoperability.htm). (I removed the buttons and added the animation.

```
import javafx.animation.Interpolator;
import javafx.animation.TranslateTransition;
import javafx.embed.swt.FXCanvas;
import javafx.scene.Group;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.scene.text.Text;

import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Point;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridData;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.GridLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;

public class TwoButtons {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    TranslateTransition fTranslateTransition;
    final Display display = new Display();
    final Shell shell = new Shell(display);
    final GridLayout layout = new GridLayout();
    shell.setLayout(layout);
    shell.setSize(1000, 80);

    final FXCanvas fxCanvas = new FXCanvas(shell, SWT.NONE) {
        @Override
        public Point computeSize(int wHint, int hHint, boolean changed) {
            getScene().getWindow().sizeToScene();
            int width = (int) getScene().getWidth();
            int height = (int) getScene().getHeight();
            return new Point(width, height);
        }
    };
    fxCanvas.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, true));

    Group group = new Group();

    Text fBanner = new Text();
    fBanner.setX(10);
    fBanner.setY(18);
    fBanner.setText("breaking news !!");

    fBanner.setFont(Font.font("Arial", 20));
    fBanner.setFill(Color.gray(0.3));

    /* Create the Scene instance and set the group node as root */
    Scene scene = new Scene(group, Color.AQUAMARINE);
    fxCanvas.setScene(scene);

    fTranslateTransition = new TranslateTransition();
    fTranslateTransition.setNode(fBanner);
    fTranslateTransition.setFromX(shell.getSize().x);
    fTranslateTransition.setToX(-fBanner.getBoundsInLocal().getWidth());

    fTranslateTransition.setDuration(javafx.util.Duration.millis(5000));
    fTranslateTransition.setCycleCount(TranslateTransition.INDEFINITE);
    fTranslateTransition.setAutoReverse(false);
    fTranslateTransition.setInterpolator(Interpolator.LINEAR);

    group.getChildren().add(fBanner);
    fTranslateTransition.play();

    shell.open();
    while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
            display.sleep();
        }
    }
    display.dispose();
}
}
```

The mission control tells me that during 30 secondes, I ran a lot into SWT error (about 60-70 times)

```
org.eclipse.swt.SWT.error(int)  
   org.eclipse.swt.graphics.ImageData.<init>(int, int, int, PaletteData, int, byte[], int, byte[], byte[], int, int, int, int, int, int, int)
      org.eclipse.swt.graphics.ImageData.<init>(int, int, int, PaletteData, int, byte[])    
         javafx.embed.swt.FXCanvas.paintControl(PaintEvent) 
            javafx.embed.swt.FXCanvas.lambda$registerEventListeners$3(PaintEvent)   
               javafx.embed.swt.FXCanvas$$Lambda$43.762218386.paintControl(PaintEvent)
                  org.eclipse.swt.widgets.TypedListener.handleEvent(Event)
...
```

No error when I remove the TranslateTransition.

Is there something wrong using TranslateTransition or something I missed ?

Thanks for any clue.

Comment: This looks like a bug in JavaFX => SWT bridge.

Generally speaking using animations in this integration is a bit of a problem because the integration is grabbing the offscreen graphics buffer and translates it into an image which is drawn by SWT so animation may lag - still what you see is a bug and should be fixed by JavaFX team

Comment: I work in the Java Mission Control dev team, and we also do some JavaFX/SWT embed, so I was curious to see if I could repro this, but I couldn't. I tried JDK 8 and 8u20 on Windows. I wanted to check if it was fixed, or if I could help you open a bug..